# Metered internet: How can I require every program to ask permission before internet access

Tags: windows, networking

Is there a way I can require every program that needs internet access to notify me first and then I can allow or disallow depending on real need and available data?

I have a limited data plan with my ISP, and since they are the only ones that serve where I live, I am stuck with this. I am burning through data, and I need to ensure there are only certain programs using the internet.

Comment: What is wrong with Windows Firewall or a third-party Firewall?

Comment: As it was written your question was asking for specific software, which isn't a good fit for this site and is against the rules. However, there are probably ways to do this without having to request specific software, so I've rephrased your question to remove the software request part.

Comment: I need it to ask permission for EVERY program, not just the ones it thinks is harmful. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: Like @Ramhound says, if you know what applications you actually WANT to have internet access, the best thing to do would be to configure the Windows Firewall to block the other programs. Perhaps give us a few specific programs you'd like help blocking/allowing and we can get started with that.

Comment: So, you want EVERY program to ask permission. Some you're ALWAYS deny, and some you'll allow sometimes?

Comment: Yes, exactly my goal

Comment: My problem with configuring Norton to block individual programs is that I have so many. I need it to ask whenever a program tries

Comment: "I need it to ask whenever a program tries" - I think it is a bad idea because you will spend a lot of time to respond to all such pop ups/requests instead of working on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

May be not really what you looking for, but if you go to **Advanced settings** of firewall, then on the right side panel click **properties** and change on all tabs (Private/Domain/Public) Outbound connections to `block` then no one application would be able to go out.

This will disable ALL outgoing connection and you need to setup outgoing rules after that for any program(s) you want to allow outgoing connections.

You can wrote some scripts by employing `NetSh` that might simplify managing what you want to allow at some point in time and disable when you don't need it.